# How to get all the distinct data from the columns pipe delimited

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using the below query to get the data

```
SELECT NMA.MsgAddress,CC.PagerNum,CC.Email,CC.VoiceNum
FROM [Table1] GEP (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [Table2] CC (NOLOCK) 
    ON GEP.PersonID = CC.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table3] NME (NOLOCK) 
    ON GEP.PAN = NME.Cardnumber 
    AND NME.Status = 2 --ACTIVE (Enrolment Status)
INNER JOIN [Table4] NMA (NOLOCK) 
    ON NME.MsgAddressUID = NMA.MsgAddressUID 
    AND NMA.Status = 1 --ACTIVE (Address Status)
INNER JOIN [Table5] NMAT (NOLOCK) 
    ON NMA.MsgAddressTypeUID = NMAT.MsgAddressTypeUID 
    AND NMAT.MsgAddressType IN ('MobileNumber','EMAIL')
WHERE GEP.PAN IN (TEST)
```

The output that I get is as below

[image]

Need to get the distinct result set pipe delimited as below.

```
9856235687|test@Testing.com|698754321|Prakash@gmail.com|123121212
```

The MsgAddress column is the one that's have multiple entries.

Comment: Have also tried this type of syntax
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),NMA.MsgAddress),'')+'|'+
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CC.VoiceNum),'')+'|'+
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CC.BusNum),'')+'|'+
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CC.FaxNum),'')+'|'+
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CC.EmerPhone),'')+'|'+
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CC.Email),'')+'|'+
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CC.PagerNum),'')

Though this still gives two recordset where as I need only one record set with unique values.

Comment: Can the above query be modified to show the results as below based on the available values ?

R1. If all the values are present then the above query is working awesome.
R2. If the MsgAddress value is not available it has to just show the rest of the values i.e PagerNum|Email|VoiceNum
R3. If only the MsgAddress value is present it just has to show the value 9856235687|test@Testing.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
WITH SomeCTE (MsgAddress,PagerNum,Email,VoiceNum)
AS (
    SELECT NMA.MsgAddress,CC.PagerNum,CC.Email,CC.VoiceNum
    FROM [Table1] GEP (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [Table2] CC (NOLOCK) 
        ON GEP.PersonID = CC.PersonID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table3] NME (NOLOCK) 
        ON GEP.PAN = NME.Cardnumber 
        AND NME.Status = 2 --ACTIVE (Enrolment Status)
    INNER JOIN [Table4] NMA (NOLOCK) 
        ON NME.MsgAddressUID = NMA.MsgAddressUID 
        AND NMA.Status = 1 --ACTIVE (Address Status)
    INNER JOIN [Table5] NMAT (NOLOCK) 
        ON NMA.MsgAddressTypeUID = NMAT.MsgAddressTypeUID 
        AND NMAT.MsgAddressType IN ('MobileNumber','EMAIL')
    WHERE GEP.PAN IN (TEST)
)

SELECT STUFF((SELECT '|' + MsgAddress
              FROM SomeCTE 
              FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') 
       + '|' + MAX(CC.PagerNum) + '|' + MAX(CC.Email) + '|' + MAX(CC.VoiceNum) As Result
FROM SomeCTE 
GROUP BY PagerNum,Email,VoiceNum
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks a lot @Vignesh

Comment: Can the above query be modified to show the results as below based on the available values ?

R1. If all the values are present then the above query is working awesome.
R2. If the MsgAddress value is not available it has to just show the rest of the values i.e PagerNum|Email|VoiceNum
R3. If only the MsgAddress value is present it just has to show the value 9856235687|test@Testing.com